# Using yield within a select statement

Tags: ruby

If I wanted to prune an array by a given set of parameters I would write something like this:

```
array = [4,5,6,7,8]
a = array.select{|i| i>=5}
puts a.inspect
```

which would return `[5,6,7,8]`.

I want to write a function "filter" which accomplishes the same thing. In this case my first thought is to write something like:

```
array = [4,5,6,7,8]
a = filter(array) {|i| i >= 5}
puts a.inspect
```

What I can't figure out is how to properly call `yield` within the method to invoke the code block during the `select` statement:

```
a = array.select{yield}
```

Doesn't seem to work since it attempts to call the code block on nil, not the array within the function. What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it makes sense for you, but try:

```
def filter(array)
  array.select { |i| yield(i) }
end

array = [4,5,6,7,8]
p filter(array) {|i| i >= 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write code within braces `{...}` to be passed to a method, this code is called a **block**. It is normally passed implicitly to a method (i.e. it is not a named argument). To invoke this implicit block, you call `yield`.

In your case, you don't want to invoke the block yourself; you want your `filter` method to pass the block along to `select`, where the actual filtering takes place.

To "pass along a block", you can make the method's block argument explicit by using the `&` prefix. Note that the name `block` in this example is just convention; there is no special `block` keyword. The important part is the `&` character:

```
def filter(array, &block)
  array.select(&block)
end

array = [4,5,6,7,8]
filter(array) { |i| i >= 5 } # => [5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: Both your answer and Rustams seem to work - Is there a ruby style convention about which way of solving this is preferred?

Comment: The Ruby Style Guide suggests that `&block` is the preferred convention: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#block-argument